# How to set up Grails 3 UrlMappings.groovy file so that there is no default url mapping?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails3

I have an issue that I'm facing while upgrading from Grails 2 to Grails 3. In my Grails 2 project, I had a UrlMappings.groovy file that looked like this:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        //"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        //    parseRequest = false
        //    constraints {
                // apply constraints here
        //    }
        //}

        "/$controller/$id" {
            action = [GET: "show", PUT: "update",
                      DELETE: "delete"]

            constraints {
                // to constrain the id to numeric, uncomment the following:
                //id matches: /\d+/
            }
        }

        "/$controller/$action" {
            constraints {
                action matches: /external.*/
            }
        }

        "/$controller" {
            action = [GET: "list", POST: "create"]
            parseRequest = true
        }

        "/$controller/$action/$id" {
        }

        "/$controller/search" {
            action = [POST: "search"]
            parseRequest = true
        }

        "/$controller/count" {
            action = [GET: "count"]
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(controller: 'error')
    }
}
```

This worked well as it would automatically hit a certain action when a certain format of URL was used (e.g. GET http://localhost:8090/api/test would hit the TestController's list action).

In my new Grails 3 project, I have moved the mappings to the correct location (grails-app/controllers/my.project.package), and the package is specified at the top of the file. I want the behavior to stay the same as specified in the example above. However, I see an internal server error when I hit the endpoint now.

I believe I receive the internal server error because my TestController does not have an index action in it and the URL GET http://localhost:8090/api/test is trying to hit an index action instead of the list action.

I have generated the URL mappings report for both new and old projects, and I see that the Grails 3 project's URL mappings report contains the default URL mapping ( `|    *     | /${controller}/${action}?/${id}?(.${format)?              | Action: (default action)                                |`) even though it is commented out in the URL mapping. This is still generated after performing a clean and removing the commented out bit from the URLMappings.groovy file. Could this default mapping be the issue? If so, is there a way to stop the app from using it?

One thing I have tried is using a constraint like `controller(validator: { return false })` in the constraints block of the mapping for `"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"`. Another thing I have tried is using a different format for my custom URL mappings like

```
get "/$controller/$id"(action: "show")
put "/$controller/$id"(action: "update")
delete "/$controller/$id"(action: "delete")
get "/$controller"(action: "list")
post "/$controller"(action: "create")
post "/$controller/search"(action: "search")
get "/$controller/count"(action: "count")
```

Unfortunately, I did not have any luck with either of these solutions. I did have luck with using the static controller names (e.g. `"/test" { controller = "test", action = [GET: "list", POST: "create"] }`), but I would have to do this for many different controllers which isn't great for me.

Please let me know if anyone has worked around or solved this issue. I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Most likely the mapping is coming from a plugin. Look at the plugins you have and see if any of them have the default UrlMappings file

Comment: @JamesKleeh Yes! That was it. The project is using a Grails 3 plugin that still had the default mappings in the UrlMappings file. The file had the same mappings in the Grails 2 version of the plugin, but it wasn't getting included in the plugin package when used in Grails 2 projects as far as I can tell. Perhaps that's why I was getting confused. Thank you for your help!